# Why throttle in js not call target func outside the timeout?

Tags: javascript

I found most of the `throttle` func is like following:

```js
const throttle = (func, time) => {
    let timer
    return function (...args) {
        if (timer) return
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func(...args)
            timer = null
        }, time)
    }
}
```

My question is the target `func` which inside the `timeout` will always delay for `time` we set. So why not use target `func` outside the `timeout` so that when first call `throttle`, the target `func` will excute immediately? Like following

```js
const throttle = (func, time) => {
    let timer
    return function (...args) {
        if (timer) return
        func(...args) // outside the timeout
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            timer = null
        }, time)
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's the design decision they took when writing this version of `throttle`...

Comment: It's the difference between executing the last possible value and the earliest possible value. Say you have an input that you throttle, they type `1`, you call this, then wait 250 ms. In the meanwhile they type the second number - its now `12`, but you only responded to it when it had `1` and you ignored it when it said `12` because you were throttling. Your UI would be behind. Doing it after the delay means you have at least the most up to date value.

Comment: We can't tell you the design requirements of some unknown person who wrote the code that you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library lodash comes with a throttle function which has properties that can customize whether the function should be called at the beginning (`{ 'trailing': false }`) or right at the end (`{ 'leading': false }`)

```js
const clickedMyBtn = (time) => {
  console.log(`Click fired at the ${time} of the throttle`)
}

const throttleFireAtStart = _.throttle(() => clickedMyBtn('start'), 2000, { 'trailing': false })
const throttleFireAtEnd = _.throttle(() => clickedMyBtn('end'), 2000, { 'leading': false })

document.getElementById('throttleFireAtStart').addEventListener('click', throttleFireAtStart)
document.getElementById('throttleFireAtEnd').addEventListener('click', throttleFireAtEnd)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="throttleFireAtStart">Fire throttle at start</button>
  <button id="throttleFireAtEnd">Fire throttle at end</button>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funny how they allow both to be set to false without even a warning (both set to true makes some sense though) But I don't think that really answers the question at hand.

Comment: @Kaiido, both set to `false` haha yeah , seems like a glitch. and yeah was aware this does't directly answers the question , not by a long shot but still wanted to give a `framework/library` perpective of things (i know thats discouraged on here), ofcourse the correct thing to do would be to break down the source code of `_. throttle()` itself.

Comment: Well I believe this could be the ground of a correct answer for this incorrect question, for instance you could explain that it's purely a design choice, as can be seen in popular libraries offering options for both behaviors.